# Hibernate Mapping Annotation without Foreign Key

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have 2 tables ( Member, Department)
Member with MemberID, MemberName, DepartmentID
Department with DepartmentID, DepartmentID

Member is one to one to Department,
Department is one to many Member

Is there any ways to map them while creating the model class without using foreign key constraint in database?

Comment: Yes, you could add a `@Transient` field `List<Member> members` to a `Department` and populate it using `@EntityListeners` at `Department` "by hand" using the ID.

Comment: @Smutje 
Can I map in the Member Class? Because I want to get the member's department when I load the selected member.

Comment: Sure, when loading a `Member`, you can use its `DepartmentID` to load a `Department` out of your database and set it as `@Transient private Department department` field on your `Member`.

Comment: @Smutje Sorry to ask that, would you mind to show me example?

Comment: _Member is one to one to Department, Department is one to many Member_ It is impossible :)